# Android interrupt threads on button click - avoiding race condition

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, android-bluetooth

I have an android app designed to pair with other phones and send/receive data over bluetooth. Specifically, when a user clicks a button, it will start discovery, connect to a phone, open a socket etc. In general this works, however, I also want to set it up so that during this whole process, if the user clicks the button again, it will correctly close/stop this process. The problem I'm having is that when the user clicks to stop, sometimes it will close a socket prematurely while the app is still trying to check for incoming data because this is all happening across multiple threads. I'm trying to find the correct way to handle this

So when the user clicks to start the process, discovery will happen and then it will try to connect to the paired device over a socket:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            mmDevice = device;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            while(!this.isInterrupted()){
                BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

                // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
                try {
                    // SERVICE_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                    tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SERVICE_UUID);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mmSocket = tmp;

                if(mmSocket != null){
                    try {
                        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                        // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                        mmSocket.connect();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Socket connected");

                        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                        connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
                        connectedThread.start();

                        break;
                    } catch (IOException connectException) {
                        // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                        Log.d(TAG, "Unable to connect socket: " + connectException.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Closing socket");
                mmSocket.close();
                this.interrupt();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Once the socket has connected, I start a different thread to set up the datastreams:

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
                this.interrupt();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

So this all works as far as sending/receiving data goes. But when the user clicks the button a second time to stop the entire process (or kill the connection if it already exists) I get an error. On pressing Stop the following code gets executed:

```
if(btHelper.discoveryStarted){
    this.discoveryStarted = false;
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
}

//Stop socket connection
if(connectThread != null & connectedThread != null){
    connectedThread.cancel();
    connectThread.cancel();
}
```

The error I get is an ioexception: `bt socket closed, read return: -1` and its pointing to the line where I'm trying to read from the datastream:
`bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer)`

So the problem is that its trying to read from the stream, but on button click I have already told the socket to close, therefore theres no socket to read from. Whats the correct way to interrupt these threads to avoid a race condition like this?

Furthermore, how do I set this up so that regardless of where the user is in this process the appropriate threads/sockets/connections will be closed correctly? (for example, sometimes the socket will be opened, but data streams have not been set up yet, vs both/neither have been created)